# Adding background color of notes to Sphinx-generated PDF files?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am able to generate notes using the Sphinx directive `.. notes::`. However, the notes in html file have a background color while those from the generated PDF don’t.

How can I add color to Sphinx-generated PDF files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add something like this in your `conf.py` file (see the [doc](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-latex_elements) for the options for the LaTeX output):

```python
latex_custom = r'''
\definecolor{Admonition}{RGB}{221,233,239}

\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{admonitionbox}{
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
  }{
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
    \colorbox{Admonition}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}
  }

  \renewenvironment{notice}[2]{
    \begin{admonitionbox}
  }{
    \end{admonitionbox}
  }
\makeatother
'''

latex_elements = {'preamble': latex_custom}
```

This is a basic example, it will change the background color of all the admonitions boxes (note, warning, tip, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

My solution is inspired by the Nicolas' answer. It is built on top of the original sphinx code found in `./_build/latex/sphinx.sty`. In contrast to Nicolas' solution, this one preserves the original Sphinx layout (spacings, frames, etc.) and adds the background color to it. Additionally, it differently treats `lightbox` (note, hint, tip, important) and `heavybox` (warning, caution, attention, danger, error) admonition box styles.

Add the following piece of code in your `conf.py` file
(the final output should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEE3x.png)):

```python
latex_custom = r'''
\definecolor{AdmonitionHeavyColor}{RGB}{255,204,204}
\definecolor{AdmonitionLightColor}{RGB}{238,238,238}

\makeatletter

  \renewcommand{\py@heavybox}{
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
    \setlength{\py@noticelength}{\linewidth}
    \addtolength{\py@noticelength}{-4\fboxsep}
    \addtolength{\py@noticelength}{-2\fboxrule}
    %\setlength{\shadowsize}{3pt}
    \Sbox
    \minipage{\py@noticelength}
  }

  \renewcommand{\py@endheavybox}{
    \endminipage
    \endSbox
    \savebox{\@tempboxa}{\fbox{\TheSbox}}
    \colorbox{AdmonitionHeavyColor}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}
  }

  \renewcommand{\py@lightbox}{
    {%
      \setlength\parskip{0pt}\par
      \noindent\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}%
      %\par\noindent\vspace{-0.2ex}%
    }
    \setlength{\py@noticelength}{\linewidth}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}
    %\setlength{\py@noticelength}{\linewidth}
    \addtolength{\py@noticelength}{-4\fboxsep}
    \addtolength{\py@noticelength}{-2\fboxrule}
    \Sbox
    \minipage{\py@noticelength}
  }

  \renewcommand{\py@endlightbox}{
    \endminipage
    \endSbox
    \savebox{\@tempboxa}{\fbox{\TheSbox}}
    \colorbox{AdmonitionLightColor}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}
    {%
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
      \par\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}%
      \par\vspace{-0.5ex}%
    }
  }


\makeatother
'''


latex_elements = {'preamble': latex_custom}
```

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions you can use the `sphinx_setup` key of `latex_elements` in your `conf.py` to achieve this for *some* admonitions rather easily, so something like:

```py
latex_elements = {
    'sphinxsetup': 'warningBgColor={RGB}{255,204,204}'
}
```

Would change the warning background color to red. Check out the [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html#the-latex-style-file-options) for more info.

As of writing `noteBgColor` doesn't seem to be an option so this wouldn't help specifically for what was in the OP but could help for other admonitions.

Answer (score 1):

Use latex if then else to create different colored boxes for different admonitions. Add this to the `conf.py`

```
latex_custom = r'''
    \makeatletter
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
    \renewenvironment{sphinxadmonition}[2]
    {
       %Green colored box for Conditions
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Conditions}}{
                         \medskip
                         \begin{tcolorbox}[before={}, enhanced, colback=green!10, 
                                           colframe=green!65!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
                                           title=\sphinxstrong{#2}, arc=0mm, drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white]}{

           %Blue colored box for Notes
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Note:}}{
                             \medskip
                             \begin{tcolorbox}[before={}, enhanced, colback=blue!5!white, 
                                               colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
                                               title=\sphinxstrong{#2}, arc=0mm, drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white]}{
               %Orange colored box for Warnings 
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Warning:}}{
                             \medskip
                             \begin{tcolorbox}[before={}, enhanced, colback=orange!5!white, 
                                               colframe=orange!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
                                               title=\sphinxstrong{#2}, arc=0mm, drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white]}{

                   %Red colored box for everthing else
                   \medskip
                   \begin{tcolorbox}[before={}, enhanced, colback=red!5!white, 
                                 colframe=red!75!black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
                                 title=\sphinxstrong{#2}, arc=0mm, drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white]}
           }
       }
    }
    {
       \end{tcolorbox}\par\bigskip
    } 

    \makeatother
'''

latex_elements['preamble'] += latex_custom
```

The output is something like this [image] [image]