# create a role (font color) in sphinx that works with `make latexpdf`

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm used to write Rest documents while I never used LaTex.

What I would like to do is create some *font color roles* that I can add inline the text (e.g. :red:`this text is red`) that work both in html and in latexpdf compilation.

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702865/sphinx-restructuredtext-set-color-for-a-single-word), but I cannot reproduce it.

I think that the *magic* will be done changing the `conf.py` file, but I didn't find out how.

Moreover, during the `latexpdf` compilation, in the `_build/latex` directory, there is a `sphinx.sty` file that contains a lot of things for the customization of the final pdf file.

If I want to change some parameter of the final pdf file, have I to edit this file, put it somewhere and tell sphinx to take this style file?

Sorry for all these stuff, but I'm a little bit confused..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

1. a 'source/_templates/layout.html' file with

   ```
   {% extends "!layout.html" %}

   {% block extrahead %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="{{ pathto('_static/custom.css', 1) }}" /> 

   {% endblock %}
   ```
2. a 'source/_static/custom.css' file with

   ```
   @import url("default.css");

   .red {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

You can now use a :red: role in your rst files. Don't forget the back tick and the clean target after html or css editions:

```
A :red:`red`text

$> make clean html
```

The global tree:

```
test-sphinx
├── Makefile
├── build
└── source
    ├── _static
    │   └── custom.css
    ├── _templates
    │   └── layout.html
    ├── conf.py
    └── index.rst
```

An index.rst example:

```
TS test!
========

.. role:: red

This is :red:`just` a test …
```

Hope this help,

Antoine

Comment: Hi Antoine.. I tried what you suggested but it didn't worked. I just pasted the code in a file (`custom.css`) in the `_static` folder and called the role in the rst files with :red:`text`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm very sorry Matteo: I should have read my notepad with my notes … I edited my previous answer and tested it this time !

Comment: Hi Antoine, thanks for you effort but it didn't work anyway. I copied and paste your code in the folders you said, but in the final draft I cannot see a red text.. By the way, once we get it to work, this role works also for pdf outputs (build with latexpdf)? Thanks again!

Comment: Bad … I've just tried again and it works there. But, about latexpdf, it's another story and I don't have the answer right now.

Comment: yes, very bad.. I tried again and again, but nothing changed... Have I to edit also the `conf.py` file?

Comment: I didn't. This is how I tested : used 'sphinx-quickstart' with almost all defaults (just put source and build separated) ; added files custom.css and layout.html; edited index.rst; make and that's all … Just made from scratch right now with success.

Comment: For latexpdf, what about the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530489/adding-background-color-of-notes-to-sphinx-generated-pdf-files?rq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87144/discussion-between-aflp91-and-matteo).

Comment: Thanks!  I used `{% extends "!layout.html" %}{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/override.css"] %}` as my layout.html file instead, which might be the "newer" way to do it.  And I did not need `@import url("default.css");` in my CSS nor did I need the `clean` option in `make html`.  Thank you works great!

Comment: In case this could help: do not leave a space between the ":red:" and the "`just`". Otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by aflp91 works for setting the color using css for the html output, but it does not change the color in the latex output.

Aflp91's answer actually generates a custom role in the tex file, which can be overwritten to change the color. All that was missing was the code to actually customize the custom role in LaTex. To do so, add the following in conf.py:

```
latex_elements = {
    'passoptionstopackages': r'\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}',
    'preamble': r'''
\newcommand{\DUrolered}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
''',
}
```

The DUrole syntax is described in the [docutils documentation](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/latex.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles).

Comment: Confirm that it works. Thanks! Sphinx 5.3.0. Only God knows how many hours I've wasted searching for a way to make formatted output which works _both_ in HTML output and LaTeX PDF. The last attempt was to store the samples in HTML, insert it with `only:: html` as `raw` code, and generate the images for PDF with the same content, like this: HTML -> SVG (wrote a translator) -> PNG (PIL). But thanks to this answer there is no need for this unimaginable monstrosity anymore.

This is how it looks like in PDF:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/af608.png

Comment: Also wrote LaTeX commands for all the colors desribed in sphinx's `s5defs.txt`, and filled the values with default HTML ones (20 colors total):

https://pastebin.com/857iDMcq